# Jackson typeId is not included in generated json

Tags: java, json, serialization, polymorphism, jackson

Have the following classes:

```
public class BaseEntity<E> {
    public TrackedChange<E> trackChange;
}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=B.class, name="b_type") })
public abstract class A extends BaseEntity<A> implements Cloneable{
    public String aFoo;

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

@JsonTypeName("b_type")
public class B extends A {
    public String bFoo;
}

public class TrackedChange<E> {
    public E tracked;
}

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, CloneNotSupportedException {

        B bInstance = new B();
        bInstance.bFoo = "bFoo";
        bInstance.aFoo = "aFoo";
        B clone = (B) bInstance.clone();
        bInstance.trackChange = new TrackedChange<A>();
        bInstance.trackChange.tracked = clone;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(bInstance));
    }
}
```

The generated JSON is:

```
{
   "type":"b_type",
   "trackChange":{
      "tracked":{
         "trackChange":null,
         "aFoo":"aFoo",
         "bFoo":"bFoo"
      }
   },
   "aFoo":"aFoo",
   "bFoo":"bFoo"
}
```

Type `("type":"b_type")` information is not included in trackChange.tracked object. How to fix this problem?

EDIT: Finally i used `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` which was introduced after release 2.3.0. It utilizes existing property to determine actual type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type erasure on `TrackedChange.tracked` is your problem.  At runtime, your type  is lost due to type erasure and the Jackson serializer cannot determine the type, and thus doesn't recognize it as `B` and doesn't find the `@JsonTypeInfo` for it; thus at runtime Jackson reads `TrackedChange.tracked` to be type `Object`.

There's various ways to mitigate type erasure in Jackson, but they typically stem around generics on collections.

There's only one way to basically achieve your goal that I can see, you can configure ObjectMapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeResolverBuilder<?> typer = new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE);
typer = typer.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
typer = typer.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
typer = typer.typeProperty("type");
mapper.setDefaultTyping(typer);
```

This will register a type mapper configuration for Object and non-concrete types during Serialization (this covers the `TrackedChange.tracked` case).  Unfortunately, I do not see any way to pre-register that this configure would use a matching `b_type` name as in your example.  The best suggestion I have is to change your class configurations to use the following, which matches the behavior configured above:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
```

Giving you output like this:

```
{
  "type" : "so.json.typeinfo.B",
  "trackChange" : {
    "tracked" : {
      "type" : "so.json.typeinfo.B",
      "trackChange" : null,
      "aFoo" : "aFoo",
      "bFoo" : "bFoo"
    }
  },
  "aFoo" : "aFoo",
  "bFoo" : "bFoo"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS to JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME and it started to work as expected!